# Externalizing client ChannelSet configuration for Flex/Java web application

Tags: java, apache-flex, web-applications, configuration, blazeds

I am looking for an approach that will allow me to (somehow) dynamically pass the server name, server port, and web context to my Flex client so it can create a ChannelSet for it's RemoteObjects to use.  These three properties are, of course, readily available to my Java server-side code so I just need a way to get them to the client.

By default, [Adobe says](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=build_apps_4.html) you should compile your Flex application against the server configuration file "services-config.xml".  This is a highly inflexible practice that [Spring says](http://forum.springsource.org/showpost.php?p=228738&postcount=1) should be avoided (I agree).

One [popular approach](http://coenraets.org/blog/2009/03/externalizing-service-configuration-using-blazeds-and-lcds/) is to use Flex's http service to download an XML configuration file.  I like this idea, but I don't want to hard-code an XML file and keep it inside my WAR file.  Is there a way to dynamically generate this from Java code?

Another idea I had is to somehow use flashvars to pass the properties in from the containing HTML page to the SWF file.  But again, I don't want to hard code them into the HTML page.  Is there a way (maybe with Javascript?) to dynamically set the value of these when the page loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I do it. I hope you'll find it useful:

```
public static function getRemoteObject(destination:String, channelName:String,
    showBusyCursor:Boolean=true):RemoteObject{
    var remoteService:RemoteObject=new RemoteObject(destination);
    var channelSet:ChannelSet=new ChannelSet();
    var url:String = Application(Application.application).url;
    var secure:Boolean = URLUtil.isHttpsURL(url);
    var protocol:String = URLUtil.getProtocol(url);
    var amf:AMFChannel;
    if (secure){
        amf = new SecureAMFChannel(channelName, protocol +
            "://{server.name}:{server.port}" +
            (Application.application as Application).parameters.contextRoot +
            "/graniteamf/amf");
    }else{
        amf = new AMFChannel(channelName, protocol +
            "://{server.name}:{server.port}" +
            (Application.application as Application).parameters.contextRoot
            + "/graniteamf/amf");
    }
    channelSet.addChannel(amf);
    remoteService.channelSet=channelSet;
    remoteService.showBusyCursor=showBusyCursor;
    return remoteService;
}
```

So as you can see the only things you need to provide are destination - which must be configured in server side XML and contextRoot - passed as flashVar. Passing as flashVar in my case (through JSP) looks like this:

```
String flashVariables = "contextRoot=" + request.getContextPath() +
    "&locale=" + request.getLocale().getLanguage();
```

Comment: This is brilliant. I get how you infer the hostname, port, and protocol from the Application.url.  However, I am a total JSP newbie...can you help me out with the other part?  Are you saying you turned your SWF html wrapper into a JSP page? Or did you put javascript in the html wrapper that invokes a JSP page?  How does that work?

Comment: It is just as you said. I've moved all html code contained in index.html generated by FlexBuilder into JSP page benefiting from all the dynamic content that JSP technology provides. If you could specify how do you plan to deploy your application we could figure out something specifically for your needs.

Comment: We do production deployments in Jetty or Tomcat (Websphere and JBoss are on the todo list however).  When using an app-server, this approach would work well.  I might also pass in the port number via flashvars rather than infer it so I could insert my CharlesPoxy for debugging.  The main thing I can't get past is how this will work with Flexmojos when it runs my Flexunit integration tests with the stand-alone player.  I don't know how to handle flashvars in that case.  Any ideas? Or do you not do that?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't test my application on standalone player (I use Tomcat plugin for FlexBuilder to deploy my application automatically) so I can't help you there. Considering Tomcat or Jetty and not knowing JSP means that your Flex application is supposed to be the main and only part of your application. If that's true then JSP should be more than enough for your needs. Just change your index.html to index.jsp, read a bit about scriptlets (or EL if you're into "bad practice" stuff) and put your new acquired knowledge to use with the code above :)

Comment: @2DH - One more question.  How does this work with the Flash Builder debugger?  Meaning what kind of launch configuration do you use to debug the Flex application.  Currently I really enjoy editing code and launching the application quickly against a Java server that I have running all day long.  It seems like this approach would require me to rebuild and redploy a WAR file before I could launch the debugger.  How does this work for you?

Comment: @2DH - I set up another SO question for this remaining issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426053/quickly-debug-flex-java-web-application-from-eclipse

Comment: BTW - I got a deprecated warning on `(Application.application as Application)` so I switched to `FlexGlobals`.